# Efficient method to import data from s3 to dynamodb by masking specific values of dynamodb attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamodb dump in s3 , I am trying to create new dynamodb tables from the dump. In the source table I have a particular attribute of type Map that I want to mask in the destination table.

I am looking for an efficient way to do this in terms of cost and effort.

There are a few solutions to import the data that I found like AWS Data Pipeline and AWS glue. What would be an efficient way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

If by masking data you are referring to client side encryption, in which you will need to be able to decrypt the data  in future for your application then you must use the SDK and the compatible encryption library to write the data into DynamoDB which prevents you from being able to use Datapipeline or Glue.

With that being said, there is nothing preventing you from using your own masking implementation, in which case you can make the data at rest while it sits in S3, then use Import from S3 or Glue to import the data to DynamoDB.

Comment: By masking I mean I want to absolutely ignore the values of certain attributes while importing the data as they are some sensitive information which I nor want to import neither use in future

Comment: In that case simply use Glue and drop those columns from your dataframe before writing.